# Flight delay history?

Tags: flight-search-engines, missed-flights, flight-status

Our United Airlines flight UA6056 from DTW to IAH was delayed on 1/1/2019 scheduled for 8:25am departure and I want to find out when it actually boarded & took off?

They told us at the gate it was delayed 1 hour and to come back to board at 9am. When we returned just before 9am the flight had already left. Without us. For our honeymoon.

Comment: FlightAware has [the history](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/UAL6056) but you'll need to purchase additional access to see that far back. Free access only shows back to 1/20.

Comment: Sounds like a terrible experience. But I'm not sure how knowing the actual departure time will help you in taking this up with the airline.